# How to write an interceptor which logs the arguments and return value?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, interceptor

I am trying to write an interceptor using `javax` interceptor `api`. It has to  log the arguments passed to a method and the return value of the method.

Below is a sample code snippet which logs the arguments

```
for(final Object object: context.getParameters()) {
    final Methods[] methods = object.getClass().getMethods();
    for(final Method method: methods){        if(method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            LOGGER.info(method.getName() + ":" + method.invoke(object));
       }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble logging complex/user-defined types.

Let's say there is a `getter` method which returns students address of type Address. My code does not check if the invoke method returns primitive or user defined type. So it prints hash code of Address when `getAddress` method is invoked.

I know that I have to write some kind of recursive code by checking the return type of the `getter` method. If the `getter` method returns user defined type then I will again use reflection to find all `getter` method and then print them.

To do this I have to use a if else condition something like below

Pseudo code:

```
type =method.getReturnType().getSimpleName();
if type != string or int or char or boolean and so on
    then
    Call the recursive method which again does the above
```

I want to know if there is a better solution. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can't you define a `toString` method in `Address` class?

Comment: That forces everyone who is using my interceptor to override toString.

Comment: Sure, but it's not a bad thing to have a proper toString in custom classes.

Comment: Yes I agree. But I cannot force. In my previous project there was an interceptor which did not force us to override. Now I don't have access to that code. I think it is possible without the toString method.

Comment: Why not use AOP using AspectJ? is this not possible with JEE?

Comment: I don't know much about AspectJ. In fact I have never used it. So I don't know if it is possible or not in jee. So I used Jackson mapper api and I achieved what I wanted. I will now look at AspectJ and check if it can provide me what I want. Thank you Bilbo

Comment: @bilbo I have read about AOP and AspectJ programming. I understood that if I have to use it, I have to use a 3pp library like jcabi. I think javaee6 interceptors is an alternative for AspectJ programming. But I don't think java ee interceptors is as powerful as AspectJ. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Not sure buddy as I don't have much of an exposure on JEE based apps, but I have used Spring AOP and your scenario seemed like it can use the help from AOP thats why I suggested it :) :) However do some research on this and do post and answer here for the solution, Please also have a look in JEE8 draft I think they are planning to provide AOP support, have a look and let everyone know

Answer (score 1):

use `method.getReturnType().isPrimitive()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29

you can find some other `is...()` methods that can be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

May be we can use Jackson Mapper api and just pass the instance to the mapper and print the result to the log.

I think this is the easiest way.